# JSQMessage possible cell size bug

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

To customize the size of `JSQPhotoMediaItem` cell in CollectionView I've created a subclass:

```
class CustomMediaPhoto: JSQPhotoMediaItem{

    override func mediaView() -> UIView! {
        return UIView()
    }

    override func mediaViewDisplaySize() -> CGSize {
        let screen = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        let screenWidth = screen.size.width * 0.6
        let size = CGSizeMake(screenWidth, screenWidth)
        print(size)        
        return size
    }    
    override func mediaPlaceholderView() -> UIView! {
        return nil
    }

    override func mediaHash() -> UInt {
        return UInt(0)
    }
}
```

But there is a bug when the cell are displayed (not always, and I can't find a linear way to reproduce the bug):

[image]

Comment: Plus information: it is possibile to ricreate that bug only in ios 10 >

Comment: have you tried to give hard code size?